# Install a trusted P7B certificate on Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I have received a p7b file from a bank which should be a signed certificate, as a response to a csr file that I have sent.

I have manged to extract a pem certificate with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.crt
```

The certificate.crt file that I extracted has the following structure:

```
subject=/C=MK/ST=// ......
issuer=/CN=XXX
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=XXX
issuer=/CN=XXX
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I am not an expert on SSL, but I assume that this is a certificate chain, since it has two certificates.

I have configured apache with the following directives:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile path/to/certs/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile path/to/certs/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile path/to/certs/private.key
```

Apache serves this properly on https, but the browser does not recognize this as a signed certificate, and gives me that Untrusted connection screen.

Am I doing something wrong, or the certificate is not signed by a trusted authority... Is there a way to check if the certificate is signed properly?

Comment: Where did the `private.key` file come from?

Comment: From a bank, as a response to a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) that I have sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the SSL configuration checker if the certificate was installed properly, refer to the link below:
http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
or
https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/en_US

You may also use this link to check who issued the certificate and details of the certificate:
http://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

Comment: the second link actually help me debug Apache configuration, and check which certificates get loaded in the chain.

Comment: Good to hear that... Are you all set now?

Comment: yeah, thanks the certificate turned out not to be signed by a trusted authority, only from the bank.